# Angular Material: Radio Button Alignment

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have the following HTML that looks something like this.

```html
<mat-radio-group aria-label="Select an option">
    <mat-radio-button>Sample 1</mat-radio-button>
    <mat-radio-button>Sample 2</mat-radio-button>
    <mat-radio-button>Unknown Sample</mat-radio-button>
</mat-radio-group>
<mat-radio-group aria-label="Select an option">
    <mat-radio-button>Yes</mat-radio-button>
    <mat-radio-button>No</mat-radio-button>
    <mat-radio-button>Unknown</mat-radio-button>
</mat-radio-group>
```

The radio buttons look like this:

[image: Radio Buttons]

I would like to modify the CSS so that the buttons of the two different groups line up vertically but I am stumped as to how I can make that happen.

Any advice would be appreciated!

[image: What i'm trying to achieve]

This is what I want it to look like. Is there any way to do this without adding whitespace manually?

Comment: I would use `grid` layout

Comment: That is kind of what I was thinking but I am not sure what kind of grid to use. Would "mat-grid-list" work or are you referring to something in CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `display: grid` to achieve this:

```css
.mat-radio-group {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
}
```

is all that you need. It will convert each radio group into three columns of 1 fragment. Read more about [Grid Layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout) and [grid-template-columns](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-columns) at MDN.

In case you have global styling enabled: be aware that you might need to use an additional CSS class, and not `.mat-radio-group`, so the styling won't be applied everywhere you use radio groups.

[image: Using display grid to show mat-radio-group]

[Here's a StackBlitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rsm9hb-yvwcnq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fradio-overview-example.css) to show above.

Comment: Yeah, that was exactly what I was going for. Thanks!

Comment: I dont have global CSS enabled but thanks for pointing that out. I did increase the "repeat(3, 1fr);" to "repeat(5, 1fr);" to make it look slightly more left aligned but that got me the look I was going for. Thanks again!